# MVC Route specific URL to specific action?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I would like to keep the regular routing of area/controller/action/id

but have 1 extra url /login that goes to /account/account/login.(area named account, controller named account, action is login)

Is there a way I can specificy this routing? My client is requesting a shorter URL to the login page.

Comment: Routes are interpreted in order. Just add a route to `/login` on top. What did you try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can simply create a route in the `RouteConfig`

**Example**

```
routes.MapRoute("Login", 
    "login", 
    new { controller = "account", action = "login" },
    new string[] { "MyApp.Areas.Account.Controllers" });
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. I have tried this: ` routes.MapRoute("Login", "login", new { area = "Account", controller = "Account", action = "Login" });` since I am using areas. However, when I try to go to the URL, the action cannot find the correct view and is not looking in /areas/account, but just /account/. I am marking this as the correct answer since it answer the question of routing, but if you have any suggestion with the action finding the correct view in this case it would be great =)

Comment: Have a look at this SO answer it may be the same issue that you are experiencing http://stackoverflow.com/a/6656959/1593273