# A route is already in the route collection for Area Route

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

Here's my main routing table for my mvc project:

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
        routes.MapRoute("Default", "{controller}/{action}/{id}", new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });
    }
}
```

And I have an area called Docs and here is its registration:

```
public class DocsAreaRegistration : AreaRegistration
{
    public override string AreaName
    {
        get{ return "Docs";}
    }

    public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
    {
        context.MapRoute("Docs_default", "Docs/{controller}/{action}", new { controller = "Wiki", action = "Index" });


        context.MapRoute("RESTApi", "wiki/restAPI/v1", new { controller = "Wiki", action = "RestAPI" });


        context.MapRoute("RESTApi", "wiki/test", new { controller = "Wiki", action = "action1" });
        context.MapRoute("RESTApi_test0", "wiki/test0", new { controller = "Wiki", action = "action2" });
        context.MapRoute("RESTApi_test1", "wiki/test2", new { controller = "Wiki", action = "productions" });
        context.MapRoute("RESTApi_test2", "wiki/test3", new { controller = "Wiki", action = "action3" });
        context.MapRoute("RESTApi_test3", "wiki/test4", new { controller = "Wiki", action = "action4" });
    }
}
```

**I'm getting the runtime error**: A route named 'Docs_default' is already in the route collection. Route names must be unique.

I don't see where there is a conflict here.  Or am I missing something?

(FYI, Ignore the names of the actions, they're just for testing purposes...so they won't make sense.)

Answer (score 7):

You are probably calling RegisterRoutes twice in Application_Start.

The problem is a duplicate `AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas(); on route and on global.asax

so need only this:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
```

OR do the below steps:-

Check your bin folder. Maybe there is another .dll that adds the same route to the RouteCollection.

This happened to me when I was renaming a project. I had 2 .dlls in my bin folder:

```
MyProject.Web.dll
MyProjectNewName.Web.dll
```

Comment: thanks. Only issue I have now is it's hitting the main route table default route.  I want it to hit my area's default route when the app starts instead.

Comment: for that just go through this link may be you will find something usefull .. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5128009/mvc-3-area-route-not-working