# Views being searched for in the wrong location

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to understand what I've broken in my MVC project. I decided that I wanted to have hyphens supported implicitely in URLs, and so I wrote a RouteHandler to do this:

```
public class HyphenatedRouteHandler : MvcRouteHandler
{
    protected override IHttpHandler GetHttpHandler(RequestContext requestContext)
    {
        requestContext.RouteData.Values["controller"] = ConvertDashToCamelCase(requestContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString());
        requestContext.RouteData.Values["action"] = ConvertDashToCamelCase(requestContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString());
        return base.GetHttpHandler(requestContext);
    }
}
```

`ConvertDashToCamelCase` simply does as the name implies and converts a string like "my-controller" into "MyController" (not strictly camelcase I know, but it's not important to this question).

In addition to this, I am using Areas, and I have them set up similar to this:

- MyController

  - Areas

    - Modals

      - MyController
    - Json

      - MyController

To clarify, I do have controllers with matching names across my different Areas, as indicated in the above example. And here are the route configurations:

```
// RouteConfig.cs
var dataTokens = new RouteValueDictionary();
dataTokens["Namespaces"] = new[] {"MyCompany.MyProject.Controllers"};
dataTokens["UseNamespaceFallback"] = false;

var constraints = new RouteValueDictionary();
var routeHandler = new HyphenatedRouteHandler();

var searchRoute = new Route("search",
    new RouteValueDictionary(new { controller = "search", action = "index" }),
    constraints,
    dataTokens,
    routeHandler
);

routes.Add("Search", searchRoute);

routes.Add(
    new Route("{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        new RouteValueDictionary(new { controller = "dashboard", action = "index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }),
        constraints,
        dataTokens,
        routeHandler
    )
);
```

For clarity, the following are the standard area registration classes generated by Visual Studio, and both inherit from AreaRegistration.

```
// ModalsAreaRegistration.cs
var dataTokens = new RouteValueDictionary();
dataTokens["Namespaces"] = new[] { "MyCompany.MyProject.Areas.Modals.Controllers" };
dataTokens["UseNamespaceFallback"] = false;

var constraints = new RouteValueDictionary();
var routeHandler = new HyphenatedRouteHandler();

context.Routes.Add("Modals_default",
    new Route("modals/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        new RouteValueDictionary(new { action = "index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }),
        constraints,
        dataTokens,
        routeHandler
    )
);
```

.

```
// JsonAreaRegistration.cs
var dataTokens = new RouteValueDictionary();
dataTokens["Namespaces"] = new[] { "MyCompany.MyProject.Areas.Json.Controllers" };
dataTokens["UseNamespaceFallback"] = false;

var constraints = new RouteValueDictionary();
var routeHandler = new HyphenatedRouteHandler();

context.Routes.Add("Json_default",
    new Route("json/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        new RouteValueDictionary(new { action = "index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }),
        constraints,
        dataTokens,
        routeHandler
    )
);
```

When I access any of these URLs:

- ~/my-controller
- ~/modals/my-controller
- ~/json/my-controller

The request is routed to the expected controller without any issues.  However, when it comes time for MVC to locate the view, it always searches in the root `~/Views` directory instead of the Area relevant to the controller.

I've been unable to discern why this is the case - I imagined that if MVC is able to route to the correct Area, from that point forward it should also be able to search the correct Views directory.

**In summary**

When I access the controller actions for controllers inside of my `Json` or `Modals` areas, MVC is searching for the associated Views inside of the root `~/Views` directory instead of the appropriate Area's directory. **Why is this happening, and can I fix it?**

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer for this, using some clues found in an answer to a different but similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6656959/1704985.

I think the issue lies in the fact that I'm manually creating the route using `new Route()` rather than the usual system of adding the route via the MapRoute method.  I suspect the MapRoute method adds an appropriate DataToken to the route to reflect the current area.

In my case, because I was manually newing up the Route, it didn't contain that all important data token.  I updated my area registration classes to the following:

```
// ModalsAreaRegistration.cs
var dataTokens = new RouteValueDictionary();
dataTokens["Namespaces"] = new[] { "MyCompany.MyProject.Areas.Modals.Controllers" };
dataTokens["UseNamespaceFallback"] = false;
dataTokens["Area"] = "Modals";

var constraints = new RouteValueDictionary(); var routeHandler = new HyphenatedRouteHandler();

context.Routes.Add("Modals_default",
    new Route("modals/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        new RouteValueDictionary(new { action = "index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }),
        constraints,
        dataTokens,
        routeHandler
    ) );

// JsonAreaRegistration.cs
var dataTokens = new RouteValueDictionary();
dataTokens["Namespaces"] = new[] { "MyCompany.MyProject.Areas.Json.Controllers" };
dataTokens["UseNamespaceFallback"] = false;
dataTokens["Area"] = "Json";

var constraints = new RouteValueDictionary(); var routeHandler = new HyphenatedRouteHandler();

context.Routes.Add("Json_default",
    new Route("json/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        new RouteValueDictionary(new { action = "index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }),
        constraints,
        dataTokens,
        routeHandler
    ) );
```

Hey presto, problem solved!